# In GKE, "kubectl get nodes" or "kubectl get pods" not working

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

In GKE, "kubectl get nodes" or "kubectl get pods" shows following result - "Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 35.238.244.7:443: i/o timeout". I have created kubernetes cluster with default 3VMs.

Comment: Do you have created a private cluster?

Answer (score 4):

This is a common error when you have not connected to your cluster yet.

Menu > Kubernetes Engine > go inside your cluster > connect

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials xxxxx--zone us-central1-c --project xxxxxx
```